# How to find out if item is selected in CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL inside custom ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, listadapter, android-actionmode

Here is my problem: I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter:

My list in `onCreate()`:

```
list = /*some list*/
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.some_list);
listView.setAdapter(new MapListAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, list));
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
});

mapListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(...) {
        // some unrelated working code 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(...) {
        // some unrelated working code  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(...) {
        // some unrelated working code 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(...) {
        // some unrelated working code 
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(...) {
        // some unrelated working code 
    }
});
```

My custom ArrayAdapter's `getView(...)`:

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);

    final ListItem entry = getItem(position);

    // setting some textviews here and so on...

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.m_l_i_checkbox);
    // my problem ^

    return view;
}
```

I know that certain list items are selected, because ActionMode bar appears as I select them and disappears as I unselect(toggle) all of them. However, I want to have checkBox that would indicate if they indeed are selected. So how do I do that? It works just fine with android.R.single_list_item_multiple_choice and default ArrayAdapter, but I want to use my custom one. Maybe I'm getting something wrong and there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implement a similar behavior custom adapter by adding a "special" field in my Item class called isSelectedOnList (Boolean). Then in the OnItemClickListener I do like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mapListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    ...Get your item here...getItem(position).setIsSelectedOnList(!getItem(position).isSelectedOnList());
}
});
```

So now my Items Array knows which items are selected. Then in the getView method I update the checkbox which is in my item layout xml:

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);

    final ListItem entry = getItem(position);

    // setting some textviews here and so on...

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.m_l_i_checkbox);
    // my problem ^

    checkBox.setChecked(ListItem.isSelectedOnList());

    return view;
}
```

This solution works for me pretty well so I didn't care to look in android's internal mechanism for selected items in multi-select lists.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is exactly the same solution I came up with, but the problem is that in this case in order for action mode to work you need to iterate list of your items to check how many of them are checked (if 1 or more - start action mode, if none - end it) and with list lots of items it's slow doing this on every click and it's very annoying to write stuff that is already implemented but not documented well (or at all, can't find any of it!)

Comment: You are right about this especially for the documentation part, however in this particular case, list iteration is the most efficient way to do it without extending some java collection class. I believe that even with the internal mechanism android will have to iterate the list in some point in order to get the selected items, so if you are worrying about speed try to keep your list size small (perhaps with some kind of filtering or lazy loading e.t.c.). I know this is pain but that's android made for :-)